# ranks within groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a typical "panel data" (in econometric terms, not pandas panel object). The dataframe has a `Date` column and a `ID` column, and other columns that contain certain values. For each Date, I need to cross-sectionally rank across IDs based on V1 into 10 groups (deciles) and create a new column called `rank_col` (take values 1 to 10) to identify rank. Then pool all the rank1, rank2,...rank10 across time to get some stats like mean,std.

This can be accomplished easily in SAS by following code and it also illustrate what my purpose:

```
proc sort data=df;
    by Date;
proc rank data=df out=df_ranked groups=10;
    var V1;
    ranks rank_col;
    by Date;
run;
```

`df_ranked` is identical to `df` except that it has  more column called `rank_col` which containes the rank group that each row belongs to.

Sorry I don't have a sample data to show the structure, a real long data is needed to illustrate. But the SAS code shows exactly what I am after.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A way I just find figured out:

```
def grouping(data):
    dec=pd.qcut(data['V1'],10,labels=False)
    data['ranks']=dec
    return data
df_ranked=df.groupby('Date').apply(grouping)
```

This assumes `dec` preserve the right position for each row.

Please post if you have a better way, or point out any mistakes in this method.

Thanks!

**Edit**: You can just return a single new `ranks` column if you do something like the following:

```
>>> df


         Date  id  V1
0  2013-01-01   1  10
1  2013-01-01   2   8
2  2013-01-01   3   6
3  2013-01-01   4  11
4  2013-01-01   5  13
5  2013-01-01   6   4
6  2013-01-01   7   2
7  2013-02-01   1   1
8  2013-02-01   2   3
9  2013-02-01   3   9
10 2013-02-01   4  11
11 2013-02-01   5   7
12 2013-02-01   6   4
13 2013-02-01   7   6
14 2013-02-01   8  14

>>> foo = lambda x: pd.Series(pd.qcut(x,10,labels=False),index=x.index)
>>> df['ranks'] = df.groupby('Date')['V1'].apply(foo)
>>> df

         Date  id  V1  ranks
0  2013-01-01   1  10      6
1  2013-01-01   2   8      4
2  2013-01-01   3   6      3
3  2013-01-01   4  11      8
4  2013-01-01   5  13      9
5  2013-01-01   6   4      1
6  2013-01-01   7   2      0
7  2013-02-01   1   1      0
8  2013-02-01   2   3      1
9  2013-02-01   3   9      7
10 2013-02-01   4  11      8
11 2013-02-01   5   7      5
12 2013-02-01   6   4      2
13 2013-02-01   7   6      4
14 2013-02-01   8  14      9
```

Comment: It's a reasonable way to do it. You could change the apply a little to only return a `ranks` Series. That would allow you to just assign a new `ranks` column to the original dataframe as the result of the `groupby/apply`. But your way works just fine.

Comment: @KarlD. Thanks for conforming. and I just found out, if I can sort the dataframe based on the groupby variable first, the groupby operation can be much faster.

Comment: @KarlD. I tried to only return rank series `dec`, the groupby will append the whole series to each row-column (cell)

Comment: If you don't mind, I can add a version that just returns a column to your answer?

Comment: @KarlD. Much cleaner!

Answer (score 3):

It could be simpler without needing separate foo

```
In [782]: df.groupby('Date')['V1'].transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 10, labels=False))
Out[782]:
0     6
1     4
2     3
3     8
4     9
5     1
6     0
7     0
8     1
9     7
10    8
11    5
12    2
13    4
14    9
Name: V1, dtype: int64
```

Assign to column

```
In [783]: df['ranks'] = df.groupby('Date')['V1'].transform(pd.qcut, 10, labels=False)

In [784]: df
Out[784]:
          Date  id  V1  ranks
0   2013-01-01   1  10      6
1   2013-01-01   2   8      4
2   2013-01-01   3   6      3
3   2013-01-01   4  11      8
4   2013-01-01   5  13      9
5   2013-01-01   6   4      1
6   2013-01-01   7   2      0
7   2013-02-01   1   1      0
8   2013-02-01   2   3      1
9   2013-02-01   3   9      7
10  2013-02-01   4  11      8
11  2013-02-01   5   7      5
12  2013-02-01   6   4      2
13  2013-02-01   7   6      4
14  2013-02-01   8  14      9
```

---

Details

```
In [786]: df
Out[786]:
          Date  id  V1
0   2013-01-01   1  10
1   2013-01-01   2   8
2   2013-01-01   3   6
3   2013-01-01   4  11
4   2013-01-01   5  13
5   2013-01-01   6   4
6   2013-01-01   7   2
7   2013-02-01   1   1
8   2013-02-01   2   3
9   2013-02-01   3   9
10  2013-02-01   4  11
11  2013-02-01   5   7
12  2013-02-01   6   4
13  2013-02-01   7   6
14  2013-02-01   8  14
```

Comment: this is also waaaay faster