# Ranking order per group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, ranking

Consider a dataframe with three columns: `group_ID`, `item_ID` and `value`. Say we have 10 `itemIDs` total.

I need to rank each `item_ID` (1 to 10) **within** each `group_ID` based on `value` , and then see the mean rank (and other stats) across groups (e.g. the IDs with the **highest** value across groups would get ranks closer to 1). How can I do this in Pandas?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23976272/1732769) does something very close with `qcut`, but not exactly the same.

---

A data example would look like:

```
      group_ID   item_ID  value
0   0S00A1HZEy        AB     10
1   0S00A1HZEy        AY      4
2   0S00A1HZEy        AC     35
3   0S03jpFRaC        AY     90
4   0S03jpFRaC        A5      3
5   0S03jpFRaC        A3     10
6   0S03jpFRaC        A2      8
7   0S03jpFRaC        A4      9
8   0S03jpFRaC        A6      2
9   0S03jpFRaC        AX      0
```

which would result in:

```
      group_ID   item_ID   rank
0   0S00A1HZEy        AB      2
1   0S00A1HZEy        AY      3
2   0S00A1HZEy        AC      1
3   0S03jpFRaC        AY      1
4   0S03jpFRaC        A5      5
5   0S03jpFRaC        A3      2
6   0S03jpFRaC        A2      4
7   0S03jpFRaC        A4      3
8   0S03jpFRaC        A6      6
9   0S03jpFRaC        AX      7
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

There are lots of different arguments you can pass to [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html); it looks like you can use `rank("dense", ascending=False)` to get the results you want, after doing a `groupby`:

```
>>> df["rank"] = df.groupby("group_ID")["value"].rank(method="dense", ascending=False)
>>> df
     group_ID item_ID  value  rank
0  0S00A1HZEy      AB     10     2
1  0S00A1HZEy      AY      4     3
2  0S00A1HZEy      AC     35     1
3  0S03jpFRaS      AY     90     1
4  0S03jpFRaS      A5      3     5
5  0S03jpFRaS      A3     10     2
6  0S03jpFRaS      A2      8     4
7  0S03jpFRaS      A4      9     3
8  0S03jpFRaS      A6      2     6
9  0S03jpFRaS      AX      0     7
```

But note that if you're not using a global ranking scheme, finding out the mean rank across groups isn't very meaningful-- unless there are duplicate values in a group (and so you have duplicate rank values) all you're doing is measuring how many elements there are in a group.

Comment: Be careful with `dense` because if the values are the same, they get assigned the same rank!

Comment: Be careful with `rank` as column name for the dataframe as it conflicts with the internal function `rank()` of Pandas

Answer (score 4):

If the dataframe is already sorted on `value`, then you can cumulatively count the position of the values in each group.

```py
df['rank'] = df.sort_values(by=['group_ID', 'value']).groupby('group_ID').cumcount(ascending=False) + 1
```

[image: res]

If you want to ordinally rank values in each group, then you can transform `pd.qcut`. This is especially useful if the sizes of the groups are the same or the ranks are meaningful across groups or there are a lot duplicates in each group.

```py
q = 10 # how many buckets to put the values in
df['rank'] = df.groupby('group_ID')['value'].transform(pd.qcut, q=q, labels=False, duplicates='drop')

# for descending order (smaller numbers have higher rank)
df['rank'] = q - df.groupby('group_ID')['value'].transform(pd.qcut, q=q, labels=False, duplicates='drop')
```

For the data in the OP, the result is as follows (note that the ordinal ranking is the same as `groupby.rank`):

[image: res2]