# How to rank within a group in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rank

I have the following data frame

A >

```
  Bucket    C   Count
PL14    XY23081063  706
PL14    XY23326234  15
PL14    XY23081062  1
PL14    XY23143628  1
FZ595   XY23157633  353
FZ595   XY23683174  107
XM274   XY23681818  139
XM274   XY23681819  108
```

Now I want to insert a new column "Bucket_Rank" which ranks "C" under each "Bucket" based on descending value of "Count"

required output  : 
B >

```
Bucket  C   Count   Bucket_Rank
PL14    XY23081063  706 1
PL14    XY23326234  15  2
PL14    XY23081062  1   3
PL14    XY23143628  1   4
FZ595   XY23157633  353 1
FZ595   XY23683174  107 2
XM274   XY23681818  139 1
XM274   XY23681819  108 2
```

I tried the solution given in the following link

[Ranking order per group in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899369/ranking-order-per-group-in-pandas?rq=1)

command :  B["Bucket_Rank"] = A.groupby("Bucket ")["Count"].rank("dense", ascending=False)

but its giving me the following error ..

```
TypeError: rank() got multiple values for argument 'axis'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError
```

Help appreciated...TIA

Comment: Yup, you need to pass `method='dense'`. Explicitly specify each keyword argument. See my answer.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `argsort`:

```
v = df.groupby('Bucket').Count\
         .transform(lambda x: np.argsort(-x) + 1)
v

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    1
5    2
6    1
7    2
Name: Count, dtype: int64

df['Bucket_Rank'] = v
```

---

If you want to use `rank`, specify `method='dense'`. It is better to explicitly specify each keyword argument so as to prevent confusion.

```
df.groupby("Bucket")["Count"]\
      .rank(method="dense", ascending=False)

0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    3.0
4    1.0
5    2.0
6    1.0
7    2.0
Name: Count, dtype: float64
```

Note that the result you get isn't exactly what you're expecting since equal counts are assigned the same rank. If you can live with that, `rank` should work just as well.