# How to convert multi-indexed datetime index into integer?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

I have a multi indexed dataframe(groupby object) as the result of groupby (by 'id' and 'date').

```
                x  y
id  date            
abc 3/1/1994  100  7
    9/1/1994   90  8
    3/1/1995   80  9
bka 5/1/1993   50  8
    7/1/1993   40  9
```

I'd like to convert those dates into an integer-like, such as

```
             x  y
id  date            
abc day 0  100  7
    day 1   90  8
    day 2   80  9
bka day 0   50  8
    day 1   40  9
```

I thought it would be simple but I couldn't get there easily. Is there a simple way to work on this?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899369/ranking-order-per-group-in-pandas) asnwer.

Comment: groupby + cumcount

Comment: since `groupby` ensures a unique index, you could `cumcount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = 'day ' + df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().astype(str)
df1 = df.set_index([s], append=True).droplevel(1)

             x  y
id
abc day 0  100  7
    day 1  90   8
    day 2  80   9
bka day 0  50   8
    day 1  40   9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the new level and create a new index:

```
lvl1 = 'day ' +  df.groupby('id').cumcount().astype('str')
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((x,y) for x,y in zip(df.index.get_level_values('id'), lvl1) )
```

output:

```
             x  y
abc day 0  100  7
    day 1   90  8
    day 2   80  9
bka day 0   50  8
    day 1   40  9
```