# How can I get the positions of a group?

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe like this

```
data = [[1, 'a'], [2, 'a'], [3, 'b'], [4, 'b'], [5, 'a'], [6, 'c']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Id', 'Group'])
```

```
Id    Group
 1      a
 2      a
 3      b
 4      b
 5      a
 6      c
```

Without changing order I need to get the position of every `Id` based on the `Group.

Basically, I want **below output**

```
Id    Group   position
 1      a         1
 2      a         2
 3      b         1
 4      b         2
 5      a         3
 6      c         1
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899369/ranking-order-per-group-in-pandas help?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Actually, it helps me at a range. However, both questions have few differences but helpful. Thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try, `transform` + `cumcount`

```
df1['position'] = df1.groupby('Group').transform('cumcount') + 1
```

---

```
   Id Group  position
0   1     a         1
1   2     a         2
2   3     b         1
3   4     b         2
4   5     a         3
5   6     c         1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do it by [`.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
df1['position'] = df1.groupby('Group').cumcount() + 1
```

[`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) numbers ***each item*** in each group from 0 to the length of that group - 1.  It is NOT an aggregated function producing condensed result.  So no need to use `.transform()` to propagate aggregated result back to each item of the whole group.

**Result:**

```
print(df1)

   Id Group  position
0   1     a         1
1   2     a         2
2   3     b         1
3   4     b         2
4   5     a         3
5   6     c         1
```