# Python exclude zero while ranking

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ranking

Please help to create ranking that excludes values = 0, null, NaN for the below df,

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Group1': ['A', 'A', 'A',
                                   'B', 'C','D'],
                        'Group2': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3',
                                   'B1', 'B2','D1'],
                        'Number': [3, 2, 4, 0, np.nan,'']
```

Expected result:

```
Group1  Group2  Number  Rank
 A       A1      3       2
 A       A2      2       1
 A       A3      4       3
 B       B1      0  
 C       B2    NaN  
 D       D1
```

Similar post but does not show on excluding zero, null, nan
[Ranking order per group in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899369/ranking-order-per-group-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`df.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html), [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`Groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
In [1704]: df['Rank'] = df[~df.Number.isin([0, '', np.nan])].groupby('Group1')['Number'].transform('rank')

In [1705]: df
Out[1705]: 
  Group1 Group2 Number  Rank
0      A     A1      3   2.0
1      A     A2      2   1.0
2      A     A3      4   3.0
3      B     B1      0   NaN
4      C     B2    NaN   NaN
5      D     D1          NaN
```

Comment: Updated the question with additional columns, the ranking should be for each group. Please recheck and suggest. Thanks,

Comment: @spartacus8w2039 I've updated the answer based on your new requirements. Please check.

Comment: only think I made change is .groupby(['Group1','Group2', other columns....)]. But, getting a "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

Comment: @spartacus8w2039 Why are you including `Group2` and other columns in groupby? If you do, your expected output will change.

Comment: I am trying to groupby a list that contains 3 other columns (i.e. Date, Group1, Group2)

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are planing, I would write something like this: `'Rank':[2,1,3,'', '']`, so you have the result that you are expecting at the output without visual information.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Animal': ['cat', 'penguin', 'dog',
                               'spider', 'snake'],
                    'Number_legs': [4, 2, 4, 0, np.nan],
                    'Rank':[2,1,3,'', '']})
```

This would be the full code for what I think you are trying to do.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).