# Order DataFrame By Group of Category as Window

Tags: pandas, dataframe, window, sql-order-by, partition

However I found several similar questions/answers, none demonstrated a "simple" manner to order a pandas dataframe by groups of categories and minimum value like window partitions. The image represents pretty well the goal.

```
data = {
    'Section': ['A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'D'],
    'Content': [3, 5, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2]
}

df_initial = pd.DataFrame(data)


data = {
    'Section': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'Content': [1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 5, 2]
}

df_sorted = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This example was the nearest one I found by keeping the whole group together

[Ranking order per group in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899369/ranking-order-per-group-in-pandas)

Cheers

[image]

Comment: Kindly provide input and output dataframe as text, not pics. Also, add the equivalent SQL code that generates the correct answer. I assume you want a pandas equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['sortkey'] = df.sort_values(['Content']).groupby('Section')['Content'].cumcount()
df.sort_values(['sortkey', 'Section'])
```

Output:

```
  Section  Content  sortkey
4       A        1        0
6       B        0        0
2       C        2        0
5       D        1        0
0       A        3        1
3       B        3        1
1       C        5        1
7       D        2        1
```

Details:

- Sort by Content first to order
- Groupby section and use cumcount to get order in each section
- Lastly, sort the dataframe first my the new created sortkey and
  section.
- You can drop sortkey add `.drop('sortkey', axis=1)`

Comment: Bullseye @Scott . I also tried a slightly different input, just to ensure the logic which worked as well. ```data = {
    'Section': ['XA', 'AC', 'AC', 'DB', 'XA', 'DR', 'DB', 'DR', 'XA', 'DB'],
    'Content': [3, 5, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 6, 3]
} ```